# Upload image to a real web server is not working

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I'm making a simple PHP application which can upload an image to server.

I did it in my localhost, everything works well, but when I did it in real server. I mean web.com, it didn't work.

Here is my PHP script :

```
<?php


require "init.php";

$encoded_string=$_POST["encoded_string"];
$userfname=$_POST["userNameOf"];

$decoded_string=base64_decode($encoded_string);

$string= str_replace(' ','', $userfname);

$path="http://mybookshare.com/photos/" .$string. ".jpg";




file_put_contents($path,$decoded_string);

$query = "UPDATE user SET ProfPicture='$encoded_string'  WHERE UserFN='$userfname' AND ProfPicture IS NULL";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($result) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failed";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The script is located in `htdocs/app`, and the upload file destination of the picture is at `htdocs/photos`

Any help please?

Comment: You need to create the `photos` directory manually in your online hosting server script directory and give `777` CHMOD Permission to the directory in order to make it work..! And also remove the full url as : `$path="photos/" .$string. ".jpg";`

Comment: how to make it manually please ?

Comment: Use `FTP` to connect to your hosting server or you can use your `cPanel` to do it..!

Comment: i already made one u mean create new folder at htdocs right ?

Comment: You should take a look at what entries you get in the http servers error log file. That will tell you exactly what the actual issue is, instead of you having to _guess_ what it might be.

Comment: You said you tried it on your online server and it's not working why are you talking now about `htdocs` then as they are mostly available in localhost server as by default comes with `XAMPP`

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to your page at the begining after php starting tag and try again and let us know if you get any error..!

Comment: file_put_contents(photos/Ramirami.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
/data/15/4/29/107/4518922/user/5357041/htdocs/app/UploadProfPic.php
on line20

Comment: Are you on localhost server or online at your hosting server??

Comment: hosting server online

Comment: And what type of package software you are using i.e `XAMPP` etc???

Comment: Are you willing to use another code If I write one for you???

Comment: i moved the photos folder into the app folder which contains the php scripts and it worked thanks guys :)

Comment: thx alot Umair i really apperciate the help you gave me

Comment: I posted an answer so it would be good to mark the answer as accepted to consider this question solved..! also let us know if you have other problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :**
You don't have `photos` directory as in your script directory.

**Solution :** 
Try to move your `photos` directory from your sub directory to your script main directory where your PHP file is present and then you will have no errors.As you can see that the script says that your directory is not present so that's why it's failing to do the rest of process.

**Heads Up :**
I already said the same thing in my first comment but seems like you didn't give much attention to it.as you were mentioning the photos directory as to be present in your php script directory for your php to work it out with that and then you were not having the photos directory there so that's what was causing the error.!